# Client app for Hyperledger fabric first network

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric-ca

I have followed the first network tutorial and completed building a network and registering admin and users. But i'm not able to sent transaction or query to network from node client sdk.
Is there any tutorials for connecting the [first network](http://://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/build_network.html) to node app?

Answer (score 0):

in case you mean that you want to submit transaction and query ledger you can use composer-rest-server to discover your network, transactions and queries API's or you can do the following :

from composer-client module you can do this as following :

1- in your node app

```
npm install composer-client@0.20.0
```

in case you use fabric 1.2

then

```
const { BusinessNetworkConnection } = require('composer-client');

const bizNetworkConnection = new BusinessNetworkConnection();

const businessNetworkDefinition = await bizNetworkConnection.connect(cardName);
```

while cardName will depend on the participant allowed to submit transactions

```
  const factory = businessNetworkDefinition.getFactory();
  const transaction = factory.newTransaction('Name Space', 'Type');

  await bizNetworkConnection.submitTransaction(transaction);
```

that's will be on the level of transactions.

on the other hand from the on the query level you can try:

```
const queryRes = await bizNetworkConnection.query('predefined query name');
```

that's in case you have defined query or you can use buildQuery to build your own query:

```
const query = await bizNetworkConnection.buildQuery(query body);
```

then you can execute the query you have been built.

Comment: i'm not using composer